# Difference between reference binding and type conversion in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, types, reference, type-conversion

If the `reference binding`(initialization or pass into as function argument) is `implicit type conversion`.

if not, why some `casting expression`(static_cast, const_cast...) support to cast a `non-reference entity` to `reference` and I think it's reasonable to put everything unified. And further more, if reference is a part of type?

```cpp
struct class A {};
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    static_cast<int &>(a);
    static_cast<int &&>(1);
    const_cast<A &&> (A()); // funny , const_cast<int &&> (1); doesn't work
    const_cast<int &>(a);
    const_cast<int && >(a);
    static_cast<int &&>(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is designed considering that coders never make any mistake, so when one pass an argument to a function or initialize a variable, the compiler try to find a conversion that will make the code compile.

Those conversions are also considered for reference binding. In the best case, the reference is directly bound to the entity that initializes it. In the worst case, the reference is bound to the result of a *temporary materialization*. I say the worst case because temporaries are usually destroyed at the end of the full expression which makes them a major cause of dangling reference.

For example in the expression `static_cast <int &&>(1)`, a temporary is created that hold the value `1`, the reference is bound to this temporary, the temporary is destroyed and then the reference is returned. That songs crazy no?

There are so many similar ways to create such dangling references that almost no developers are aware of! For example:

```
vector <int> a {1,2,3,4};
auto && x = ++ a.begin();
auto cond = x != a.end();  //BOOOM

string f();

auto && s = f()+="10";
auto first_char = s[0]; //BOOOM
```

[Demo on compiler explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/rcc4Gh)

Temporaries are also materialized for binding to the implicit object parameter. In C++ it could be possible to avoid such mistake by applying a drastic rule: never return a reference that may refer to a temporary. But this rule is really difficult to apply in practice and is not even followed by the standard library or the core language: the implicitly declared assignment operator is not ref qualified.

Honestly I love C++ but I think the language is not safe at all, it is designed on an idealistic conception of the coder that stroke my ego. So I suppose C++ has such success for two reasons: because of its backward compatibility with C and because succeeding in writing codes that compile and run as expected is a demonstration of how intelligent are the coders!

Comment: So if the reference binding uses the same machnism as type conversion?

Comment: And I tested your two cases, they don't boom!!

Comment: Reference binding uses type conversion: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref

Comment: I exptected so, but I didn't find any related thing in chapter of `implicit type conversion` in cppreference and in google.

Comment: @BAKEZQ These two case sare *undefined behavior*. In a large code with optimization on they may cause problem. This is why dangling reference are very very bad. The compiler does not notice it, in debug mode you may not notice it, maybe not even in release mode with optimization on. But one day, you change a function, and the dangling reference created in an unrelated function start to make its job: your code run but does not behave as expected. You check your code, find nothing, you check the execution around where the surprising behavior appear, and ... you find nothing.

Comment: @BAKEZQ Recently Microsft engineer have evaluated the cost of those bugs to be around 250000$.

Comment: ok, I'll remember these rules. But I am still confused, no one talked about the reference binding related to type conversion, I can't help to think that they are different things.

Comment: @BAKEZQ I added a link that showes the consequence of undefined behavior. To make it I just added unrelated code! Try the link and def or undef SURPRISE.

Comment: why changing `f() += "asd"` to `f() + "asd"` makes the program run, I think they are both prvalues.

Comment: Again, you have not answered my question, I already know there are a bunch of undefined behavior in c++, and I am not intersted to see more.

Comment: @BAKEZQ I have written "Those conversions are also considered for reference binding". What are you looking for?

Comment: `f() += "asd"` binds the result of `f()` to the implicit object parameter of `operator =`. This operator returns a reference to this temporary which is then destroyed after initialization of `s`. If you replace by `f() + "asd"` the `operator +` return a prvalue that initialize a temporary directly bound to `s` and a special rule in C++ extends its lifetime so that `s` is never a dangling reference.

Comment: So, ref binding can be grouped into implicit conversion?

Comment: Yes, and for most of the conversions involving user defined conversion sequence as the source of the conversion is bound to the argument of a conversion function or constructor

Comment: it's a bit hard to realize this sentence.

Comment: @BAKEZQ There are to much elisium in the preceding comment (because I am lazy when I type text with my phone), an example is better: https://godbolt.org/z/dxn1jd